# ViewController displaced vertically by 20px after modal is dismissed: iOS4 Only. Example code included

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller, ios4

I hope someone can help... This issue has been discussed here and I have tried the solutions suggested but to no avail.

My problem is best illustrated using the example project which can be downloaded from this URL:

http://www.hitsalive.com/tmp/VCTest.zip

In the example project I have a main `UIViewController` with two buttons used to call two other UIViewControllers - one using `presentModalViewController` and the other using "addSubView" (using the AppDelegate). Individually both buttons and `UIViewController`s work fine.

However, if I first call the modal viewcontroller, then dismiss it (using `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES`) and then display the second (`addSubView`) `UIViewController`, then all elements and subviews in the second `UIViewController` (such as the button in the example) get displaced downwards vertically by 20 pixels. And the displacement happens with a momentary delay.

This issue does not happen with SDK 3.2 and below -- just iOS4.

Any help would be appreciated, especially with reference to the example project above.

Comment: The zip file linked to in this question is no longer available. This makes the question no longer of use to anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `[aViewControllerTwo setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];` to your `- (void)flipToViewControllerTwo` after `ViewControllerTwo *aViewControllerTwo = [[ViewControllerTwo alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerTwo" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];`

Comment: Thanks GameBit. That does work but with that solution you get strange artifacts just as the viewcontroller displays - the text in the "Dismiss" button shifts slightly after the  viewcontroller comes into view, and the text in the TextView controller initially (momentarily) displays as a black dot in the top left-hand corner.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this you need to do the following with the view controller that appears shifted: add a frame, then set the position of this frame appropriately. Set this frame to the view of the ViewController.

```
shiftedViewController* ShiftedViewController = [[ShiftedViewController alloc] init ];

CGRect theFrame = [shiftedViewController.view frame];
theFrame.origin.y = 20;
theFrame.origin.x=0;
[shiftedViewController.view setFrame: theFrame];



[self presentModalViewController:shiftedViewController          
                    animated:YES];
```